# Registration Screen datefield validation!

Tags: blackberry, boolean, validation, alert

I'm writing code for RegistrationScreen (blackberry mobile app) and i am having problems with the Datefield and it's validation. 
This is how i get the date:

```
  final Date currentDate = new Date();
  dateField.setDate(currentDate);
  dateField = new DateField ("Birthday:", 567993600, DateField.DATE | DateField.FIELD_LEFT){

        public void paint(Graphics g){

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
            super.paint(g); } 
                    };;;
```

(What do i have to modify, if i see that i have too, to get date in my timezone (lisbon))? (It shows the Date in the fallowing format: 14 Aug 2011)

Then the rest of the operations considering the datefield and all others, take place inside the `SubmitButton` `setChangeListener`

```
SubmitButton.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() {
                    public void fieldChanged( Field arg0, int arg1 ) { 

    //I think the fallowing step saves data as a String in bDayString 

      String bDayString = dateField.toString();
```

Now, to validate the date i have to split it into tokens, which i do invoking the method splitString:

```
String[] formatdate = UILib.splitString(bDayString, "");
```

Is all this correct?
If so, could you help me about this field validation? Creating a class, that i would store in Utilities Class and then call in the Registration screen. I think i have to take the Gregorian Calendar in consideration.

example of validation call (but this doesn't work for blackberry)

Check Date correctness

```
if (!UILib.isDateValid(bDayString))

{
     Alert("Register Error", "Invalid date", false);
            return;
                        }
```

Can anyone help me, please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just curious why you are setting the date on the DateField and then immediately assigning it to a new DateField?

Also maybe the [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html) class will be of some help to you?  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: It was a really dumb mistake. I didn't really think it through. I was trying to make shure that i had to do that to show the current date and then the user would then pick his birthday date. Yes, i figured out the solution with SimpleDateFormat. Thank you!